# Что лучше использовать движение через velocity или движение анимацией в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Все привет, возник такой вопрос. Что лучше использовать для передвижения персонажа. Velocity или передвижение анимацией?
В чем плюсы и минусы того и другого?

Comment: а как это "передвижение анимацией"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский с помощью root motion. Как то так https://prnt.sc/11789hn

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы про setFloat? Это же вроде просто изменение перехода анимаций, а не управление движением

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вот допустим анимация взята с mixamo, у нее не стоит параметр "in place", из-за этого анимация "перемещает" объект. Ну, а с помощью SetFloat я передаю значение, чтобы в blend trees анимация начиналась проигрываться и переходы были более плавные. Стоит так делать?

Comment: Вопрос лишен смысла. Физика и анимация это не взаимозаменяемые вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Важно понимать, что если ты начинающий в unity, то твоей задачей является просто выполнить поставленную задачу, но если ты уже задумался о такой вещи, то есть addforce или ты можешь управлять через Vector2(если 2d).MoveToward или другие параметры которые способствуют этому, всё зависит от конкретной задачи и 2d это или 3d.

Comment: Рассматриваю 3D. Я так понял, что лучше все это делать при помощи физики, а не как я пробовал?

Comment: Просто velocity и addforce я пробовал. Отсюда и появился вопрос, что лучше использовать. Или какой то способ под конкретный случай, например, velocity для движения, а addforce для прыжка.

Comment: "например, velocity для движения, а addforce для прыжка. –"
Всё верно